# Middleware not executed by Django

Tags: django, middleware

I am trying to include a middleware in a Django project, but it seems the middleware is not being executed by Django. The idea is to impersonate another user account when having app-administrator privileges.

The MIDDLEWARE section of my settings.py file looks like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'mird_project.monitor.middleware.impersonateMiddleware.ImpersonateMiddleware',
]
```

The middleware class looks like this:

```
from .models import Usuario

class ImpersonateMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_request(self, request):

        us_obj = Usuario.objects.all().filter(id_usuario=request.user.username).first()
        tipo = us_obj.tipo.id_tipo

        if tipo == "AD" and "__impersonate" in request.GET:
            request.session['impersonate_id'] = request.GET["__impersonate"]
        elif "__unimpersonate" in request.GET:
            del request.session['impersonate_id']

        if tipo == "AD" and 'impersonate_id' in request.session:
            request.user = Usuario.objects.get(id_usuario=request.session['impersonate_id'])

        return None
```

I inserted an `assert False, request` inside the `process_request` method so that it would abort execution with an exception and show me what request contained. It never even got executed, so I assume the middleware never gets executed. It doesn't throw any kind of error and the impersonation mechanism just displays the same administrator user in the site.

Any ideas why the middleware isn't being called?

Comment: What version of Django do you use?

Comment: I'm using Django 2.1

Comment: Are you sure that path is right? If so, your `models.py` is in `mird_project.monitor.middleware`, which would be unusual.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are mixing old and new style middleware APIs. The `process_request()` method is pre-Django 1.10 and won't get called automatically unless your middleware class uses [MiddlewareMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin).

You'll need to call `process_request()` yourself from the `__call__()` method:

```
def __call__(self, request):
    self.process_request(request)  # Call process_request()
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

Or alternatively you could inherit from `MiddlewareMixin` so that `process_request()` is called by Django. However it would only make sense to do that if you need to make the middleware backwards compatible.

Comment: I modified the `__call__` function as you said, which made perfect sense to me, and it still won't be called. I even tried moving the body of the `process_request` function inside the `__call__` function but it doesn't get called. What else could I try?

Comment: Have you tried placing the `assert False` as the first line in `__call__` itself?

Comment: I have an `assert False, request.GET` as the first line in `__call__`.

Comment: Also, as mentioned in the comments, your models import seems to be importing from the `mird_project.monitor.middleware.middleware` package by means of the relative import. Perhaps you mean `from mird_project.monitor.models import Usuario`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I modified the import accordingly now.